# Why does adding a specific service reference cause Visual Studio to slow down?

Tags: web-services, soap, visual-studio-2013

There's a (Java, apparently...) service reference that, when added to our solution, slows Visual Studio to a crawl. Every time any edit is made to the code, the IDE maxes out the processor and you don't get to do anything else for several seconds.

This kind of thing happens to me constantly when I'm adding references for these kinds of services. Am I doing something wrong, or is this just part of living with SOAP?

Comment: Well, that's good. Any idea what's wrong? :)

Comment: Same thing is happening to me... did you figure out what was wrong?